# Group by several columns and print

Tags: r, group-by

I have a data frame where I want at the end to print the results of several columns grouped by the number of observations of each column and their frequency separately.

This is what I have done, but it gives me the count and freq of the total but I want for each column, q1a, q1a_30d,q1a_60d,q1a_90d

```
a<- df %>% group_by(q1a, q1a_30d, q1a_60d,q1a_90d) %>% summarise(cnt = n()) %>%mutate(freq = formattable::percent(cnt / sum(cnt),1))
```

and then for print

```
kable( a, col.names = c(" ", "cnt", "freq"),align = c("lcr"),longtable = T, booktabs = T, valign = 't', escape = F,  caption = '<b> Wore a face covering or mask<b>')  %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hold_position"),full_width = T,position = "center",html_font = "Arial") %>%
  add_header_above(c("Baseline", "30 days", "60 days", "90 days"))%>%
  column_spec(border_left = T, border_right = T)
```

```
dput(a[1:10, ])

structure(list(q1a = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("All of the time", "Very frequently", "Somewhat frequently", "Never", "No answer"), class = "factor"), q1a_30d = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,2L), .Label = c("All of the time", "Very frequently", "Somewhat frequently", "Never", "No answer"), class = "factor"), q1a_60d = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("All of the time", "Very frequently", "Somewhat frequently", "Never", "No answer"), class = "factor"), q1a_90d = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L,5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("All of the time", "Very frequently", "Somewhat frequently", "Never", "No answer"), class = "factor"), cnt = c(8L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 1L), freq = structure(c(0.347826086956522, 0.0434782608695652, 0.0434782608695652, 0.565217391304348, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5), formattable = list(formatter = "formatC", format = list(format = "f", digits = 1), preproc = "percent_preproc", postproc = "percent_postproc"), class = c("formattable", "numeric"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(q1a = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("All of the time", "Very frequently", "Somewhat frequently", "Never", "No answer"), class = "factor"), q1a_30d = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,2L, 2L), .Label = c("All of the time", "Very frequently","Somewhat frequently", "Never", "No answer"), class = "factor"),q1a_60d = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("All of the time","Very frequently", "Somewhat frequently", "Never", "No answer"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:4, 5L, 6L,7L, 8L, 9:10), ptype = integer(0), class = ("vctrs_list_of","vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please share enough sample data to illustrate your problem. Use `dput` to make it copy/pasteable and include class/structure information, e.g., `dput(df[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows -- choose a suitable subset.

Comment: Please edit your question via „edit“ rather than putting your data in a comment.